# IF condition throwing error in Unix Command Prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Below is my simple if command which throws command not found but any it prints else part value...

```
-bash-3.00$ if ["$a"="10"]; then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi;
```

output:

```
-bash: [10=10]: command not found
hi
```

Can any one please let me know what is the problem ?

Comment: Friendly reminder that there are automated [linting and analysis tools](http://www.shellcheck.net) for these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add spaces between `[`/`]` and predicate expression:

```
if [ "$a" = "10" ]; then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi;
#   ^           ^
```

`[` is a program:

```
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

Without space, `[10=10]` is recognized as a program name and is executed instead of `[`.

---

```
$ a=10
$ if [ "$a" = "10" ]; then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi;
hello
$ a=20
$ if [ "$a" = "10" ]; then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi;
hi
```

Comment: I thought he also need to use -eq instead = . Is that right ?

Comment: @Priyatham51 since both arguments are quoted, = is fine

Comment: @KeithThompson It's actually the other way around. -eq is for numbers and = is for strings.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Yeah, I knew that (fumble fingers). I'll delete my previous comment and post a corrected version.

Comment: @Priyatham51: (Correcting my previous comment) `-eq` is for numeric comparisons. `=` is for string comparisons. `man test` or `info coreutils test` for details. Or `info bash` and look under "Bourne shell builtins" for `test`.